# Bring Container to Front of View

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have three controllers. One if the `HomeViewController` that initiates the `BlahPageViewController` and it's individual pages. The other two controllers (`BlahPageViewController` and `BlahItemViewController` deal with the `UIPageViewController` exclusively. In my `HomeViewController`, I have the following code that initializes the pages.

```
private func setPageViewController() {
    let blahPageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BlahPageController") as! BlahPageViewController

    blahPageController.dataSource = self

    blahPageController.blahs = blahs

    if blahs.count > 0 {
        let firstController = getItemController(0)!

        let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]

        blahPageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    // Setting page view controller to front of app
    pageViewController = blahPageController

    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)

    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)

    pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    // Now lets bring that container to the front.
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.headerBar)
    // BUT IT DOESN'T WORK!!!!

}
```

I have to imagine that the container goes to the forefront of the page. However when I run the app the buttons inside the container are not clickable.

Storyboard below.

[image]

Debugging the views screenshot.

[image]

What's wrong with this? Is there a better way to handle this. I don't want those buttons to move when the user flips through a page but the container is overlapped with the `BlahItemViewController`? How can I fix this?

Comment: where do you call the method `setPageViewController()`

Comment: During `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your `setPageViewController()` function you're using `addSubview()` to add the view of the UIPageViewController to your ViewController's view. This will put the view on top of all other views.

Basically you have two options to avoid this. Either inserting it as the very first view using

```
self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, atIndex: 0)
```

or below a specific view using

```
self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, belowSubview: self.headerbar)
```

That should do the trick.

### Update

Also make sure that user interaction is enabled for the container view. There is a setting in Interface Builder but you can also do it in code:

```
self.headerbar.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: I attempted both fixes replacing the `addSubview` code with both options but I'm still unable to click on the buttons. It's as if the `headerBar` is still covered up.

Comment: hhmm. that's weird. did you try using the view debugger in Xcode to see if there is something covering the headerbar?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html
also try removing self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.headerBar).
another question. do you really need the containerview there? if you're just showing some buttons, you could as well embed them in a view

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I debugged the view and posted a screenshot of how it looks on my question. It appears to show the buttons in front but I'm still unable to get it to respond. Even when I add an action that prints out a string, I get nothing in my console log. The container view is not necessary but I don't think it's the problem. Let me know what you think.

Comment: and user interaction is also enabled for the container?

Comment: Yay I fixed it. Update your answer to match enabling user interaction and I'll give you credit, bounty, etc. Such a silly error I missed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is in view that contains your page view controller.
You are adding view of page view controller as subview of view controllers view, and after that bring some `headerBar` to front. It overlaps page view controller's view.

Call

```
self.headerBar.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
```

instead of

```
self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that code does not work. It actually hides my header bar in entirety. I cannot even see the buttons on the header bar.

Comment: This way you would just add `UIViews` to a view, and the view would be still available on the last screen you set it up. Just mentioned even this code won't help for this problem. Use one of the methods  `insertSubview:`

Answer (score 0):

I think your view stacks are correct. Can you check the container's userInteractionEnabled is true. Or check if buttons are clickable without adding the childviewcontroller. So you can see if the childviewcontroller is affecting buttons' behaviors.